# Use XspLibrary (OSGI plugin) in Domino Designer

Tags: osgi, xpages

I've build an osgi plug-in to wrap existing jar files. I've been following [this guide](http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/wrap-an-existing-jar-file-into-a-plug-in/).

After building the plug-in I deploy it via an update site. I use a widget to import the plug-in into the domino designer.

> In "File > Application > Application Management" I can verify that
>   the plug-in is loaded (i.e. it shows up under
>   /workspace/applications/eclipse)

Now I build a new nsf and I can select my plug-in as a Xsp library in the xsp properties. Then it starts to act strange: I can use all exported classes from the **plug-in only** if I open then plug-in project in the domino designer, too.

> If I close the plug-in project I get two compile errors:
>
> 1. "StringUtils cannot be resolved"
> 2. "The import org.apache.commons.lang3 cannot be resolved"

Sometimes I also get the following error:

> - "The project was not build since the build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for ...."

Does anybody now why these errors occur? As I already mentioned: opening the plug-in project in the designer resolves all errors.

Yours
Detlef

Comment: are you able to "import" the plug-in in the xsp.properties file?  I was not even able to do that.

Comment: Yes I can select the plug-in in the xsp.properties file. Adding the plug-in to the xsp properties works whether the plug-in project is open or not.

Comment: Hi Detlef. Interesting observations. I'll have to look into that in more details - when writing the article I didn't do anything special with the plugin project (and it is in another working set) so Designer may just have "helped" me without I realized it....

Comment: Hi John - If you were developing the Plugin project in Designer and the project was open, it would be in your current 'workspace' which is an eclipse concept. So when designer (eclipse PDE) tries to resolve your plugin dependency for your XPages app, it finds it in your current 'workspace' (does not matter if it is in a different working set) instead of looking in the installed designer plugins. This means it can successfully find the commons.lang3 jar from there. If you close the plugin project (right-click in package explorer close project) it should then use your installed plugins instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the plugin 'unpack' after installation, at the moment your wrapped jars are hiding within your plugin jar. they need to be unpacked for Domino Designer to use them.

Presumably you created a feature project to install the plugin? Go back to the feature project, and the Plug-ins list, select the plugin and then tick the check-box next to '*Unpack the plug-in archive after the installation*'

In your update site, clear out your previously built plugins and features and then re-build this new feature into the update site.

Before installing the new version of the feature it might be a good idea to Uninstall your old version in designer: 
File -> Application -> Application Management
Then select the feature in the left pane, and then uninstall from the available tasks in the right pane.

Then re-install from your newly built update site, (or via widget deployment as you did before)

After your installation you can inspect the file system location of where your plugins install to:

```
<NotesData>/workspace/applications/eclipse/plugins
```

and verify that the plugin has been un-jarred into a folder instead of being just a jar.

Also, in the **Package explorer**, if you then open up your XPages application that is using your XspLibrary/Plugin, you should be able to see your plugin in the list of **plug-in dependancies**, and the icon next to your plugin should be a folder and not a 'jar' icon

Comment: Hi Cameron, this is interesting in connection with discussions I have seen about having to have two different plugins for the server and the designer. As I understand it you do not want it to unpack on the server? So would you need two different plugins for server and designer? /John

Comment: Hi John, I'm not aware of a reason not to unpack it on the server can you share? If you install via an NSF UpdateSite I don't think the plugins ever hit the filesystem , maybe this unpack setting is irrelevant when deployed via NSF Update Site?
However if you did want to deploy differently for designer and server, then you don't need 2 plugins, instead you would create 2 different features with both include the plugin (1 with unpack and 1 without - and 2 update sites).

Comment: Hi Cameron, thanks for your solution; it worked like a charm and there is no need for a second plug-in for the server.

Comment: Hi Cameron. 

I may just have misunderstood it. It was a discussion in relation to development of plugins (which is slightly different) - but I think it was in a pure Eclipse environment (and it might only have been related to one installation). I don't know the exact details (Nathan Freemann and someone else discussed it). I'll have a go with your suggestions above and adjust the article (though will need a little time to get to that at the moment). 

Many thanks for the insight! 

/John

Comment: Ok, my article has been updated with this valuable information. Thanks for pointing out ;-)  --> http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/wrap-an-existing-jar-file-into-a-plug-in/

Comment: Cameron, I actually ended up setting the unpack option in the feature project (after having consulted Serdar and Declan - as mentioned in the article) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Both errors mean that you need to install a dependency of xsplibrary namely apache commons lang 3.x. It is available as an OSGi bundle so you can simply add it to the target platform.